# Manage form-data + other variable sent via ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My question is probably basic, but there is the question:

I have a javascript function which sends an array via ajax to process some information...

```
  var second = $('form.contact').serialize();
  var arry = {keystatus: varId, keyname: second}
```

In php, I added the data sent via ajax a array and wrote an echo to see in ajax success, displaying via console.log.

What do I get:

[image]

My php script:

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST['keystatus']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['keyname']);

$teste['nome'] = $name;
$teste['email'] = $email;

echo json_encode($teste);
```

I needed to find a way to get separate, for example:

```
$_POST['keyname']['nome'] -> (in this example) discovery
$_POST['keyname']['email'] -> discovery@discovery.com
$_POST['keyname']['usuario'] -> discovery
```

Comment: You're serializing the form then adding the serialized data to an object. Create an object, add all the data you need from the form and all the other places, send that object as the data in your Ajax request. Or add the additional data as hidden input fields and then serialize the form and send it.

Comment: See ... That's exactly what I did.

Comment: No. You're putting the serialized form (which is a string, not an object) and add it as a value in your object.

Comment: Oh yes I saw. Could you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently adding the form data as a serialized string to an object, which you send. That's why it looks the way it does.

You can either build a new object with all data and send that object with ajax:

```
var data = {
    keystatus: varId,
    keyname: {
        nome: $("#the_nome_input").val(),
        email: $("#the_email_input").val(),
        usuario: $("#the_usuario_input").val()
    }
};
```

Or you can add the extra value (since it only seems to be one) as a hidden input field in your form:

```
// Add this to the form
<input type="hidden" value="" name="keystatus" id="keystatus" />


// In your js, add
$("#keystatus").val(varId); // Sets the value
var data = $("form.contact").serialize();
```

...now you can send data to your back end using ajax.

If you want to fetch your data like this: `$_POST['keyname']['nome']` and use the second alternative, then you need to rename your input fields to: `name="keyname[nome]"`, `name="keyname[email]"` and `name="keyname[usuario]"`.

That will give you the correct data structure and values.